# Last Method (or function) before app closes in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have some data which I want to keep for the duration of the session i.e when the app starts the data loads and can be accessed any time without fetching it again and when the app closes I want to delete the data so that when it restarts I have fresh data

Comment: You don't really have to delete that data, as long as you keep the timestamp of when you last refreshed it. If you want to force refresh when restarting, you can store a random session id to determine whether the data was fetched during the current app run or not.

Comment: Try `componentWillUnmount`. That function will be called whenever a component unmount from the view.

Comment: @Sriraman componentWillUnmount works only for components and is executed in every scene so thanks but its not what I was looking for

Comment: @MotiAzu Thanks that might just be it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just flush the data when the app starts?  You're not guaranteed  to know when the app is killed and/or if the JS thread is running.

Your app could exit when fully in a hibernate state, which means the JS thread will not be executing.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Sure it may solve the problem, but I'm looking to close a connection before my app shuts down. Therefore I need to know the last function called before the app unloads, (`componentWillUnmount` is not called).